# How to force iOS device to autoplay with audio

Tags: jquery, video

I have an autoplay video. It can run on iOS device.
But it has to be muted or the autoplay video won't work.

```
<video preload="none" autoplay webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline" playsinline="" muted="muted" loop="" poster="aaa.jpg" class="has_sound">
    <source src="aaa.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

right now I can turn on the audio by click a button. But is it possible to trigger the audio of autoplay video without click a button?

Comment: try `$('video')[0].play();`

Comment: nope. it didint work

Comment: In normal mode you can't auto play videos or audios on IOS device , you may use trick like simulate user input to auto-play videos and audios or enable user's touch

Comment: can you give any example

Comment: Check iOS version you are using. New polices allow autoplay but still keeps in mind sites’ bandwidth and users’ batteries.